# Unable to understand 1 note in devtools::check() caused by a platform-specific device (X11)

Tags: r, package, devtools, cran, r-usethis

I'm trying to upload my package to CRAN and using `devtools::check()`, but I'm not able to understand why the function is showing 1 note.

The code is available in [my repository](https://github.com/igorlaltuf/dalair/blob/main/R/consulta_pedidos.R). The check function shows the following message:

```
Duration: 44.3s

> checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
  Found an obsolete/platform-specific call in the following function:
    'consulta_pedidos'
  Found the platform-specific device:
    'X11'
  dev.new() is the preferred way to open a new device, in the unlikely
  event one is needed.

0 errors √ | 0 warnings √ | 1 note x
```

Does anyone know the reason of this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Look in [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), specifically the section *Eliminating R CMD check NOTEs*; notably, you can use `.data$X13` to avoid that note. Alternatively, you can use `utils::globalVariables(c("X1","X2",...,"X13","palavras"))` somewhere in your source code (not within a function).

Comment: Thank you! It worked partially, I still have some notes:


`> checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
  Found an obsolete/platform-specific call in the following function:
    'consulta_pedidos'
  Found the platform-specific device:
    'X11'
  dev.new() is the preferred way to open a new device, in the unlikely
  event one is needed.

0 errors √ | 0 warnings √ | 1 note x` 

Maybe the check is understanding this X11 is a R function, but it's only a column name. Any ideas?

Comment: If you already tried `.data$X11` or `utils::globalVariables("X11")`, then I have no more ideas, sorry. If you're submitting to CRAN, you may need to include some notes about that one.

Comment: Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Although it's not usually recommended, it may be worth editing your example here to include the output *after* you use `utils::globalVariables()` (to narrow the problem down to the "X11" problem, which is unique to you, unlike the "no visible binding" warnings, which are very common)

Comment: @BenBolker Done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a false positive, from [this code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b1434842427cc01b7e8301495fe0f75ef519ac01/src/library/tools/R/QC.R#L6384-L6391):

I haven't analyzed this in detail, but I think what's happening is that:

- you are using the symbol `X11` in your code (as part of a non-standard evaluation/symbolic pipeline)
- when the checking code in R looks up that symbol, it finds a function ("closure") with that name in `package::grDevices`
- it checks for *specific* 'bad' closures: `bad_dev <- c("quartz", "x11", "X11")`
- it concludes that you're using a platform-specific graphics call and complains.

This might be worth submitting as a bug report, or at least for discussion (either on `r-devel@r-project.org` or `r-package-devel@r-project.org`).